# Bolding an nsstring

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I have looked online for ways to bold a NSString and either it's not there or I can't seem to find it. I simply want to bold the word in the NSString but so far, what I have done is not woking:

```
 NSString *player1Name = [[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12] fontName];
```

I have relied on this to make "player1Name" bold but it doesn't work at all. 
When I run it I get this:

[image]

Thanks in advance to anyone who helps me figure out the solution.

Comment: where you want display nsstring in uilabel or else?

Comment: NSString is just a string of characters, no attributes, you can display a bolded string lots of different ways, but the simplest is using something that supports an NSAttrebutedString...

Comment: Use this NSAttributedString *player1Name = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"TEST_STRING" attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12]}];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSString *myString = @"My string!";
NSAttributedString *myBoldString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:myString
                                                             attributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:35.0] }];
```

Also you can set range for particular text like:

```
NSString *boldFontName = [[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12] fontName];
NSString *yourString = ...;
NSRange boldedRange = NSMakeRange(2, 4);

NSMutableAttributedString *attrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:yourString];

[attrString beginEditing];
[attrString addAttribute:kCTFontAttributeName 
                   value:boldFontName
                   range:boldedRange];

[attrString endEditing];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can not bold a NSString... Try a NSAttributedString...

```
NSAttributedString *player1Name = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"name" attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12]}];
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAttributedString_Class/

**fontName** is a property on UIFont

```
[[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12] fontName]
```

returns the font name **HelveticaNeueInterface-MediumP4**

Comment: ou won't see it until you set it in an "attributedText" (not "text") property on an UI element on screen. Such as UILabel, UITextField, UITextView... Where are you putting it?

Answer (score 0):

You can't make NSString bold. Instead of that you can make UILabel text into bold. Because UILabels are for UI representation & NSStrings are just objects. So make your UILabel bold

```
[infoLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16]];
```